# getting sessionid with javascript

Tags: javascript

Under the headline:

> Finding the session id with javascript in the browser

from this link:

[Link to Autopilot](http://docs.autopilot.apiary.io/#reference/api-methods/addupdate-contact/add-or-update-contact?console=1)

it says that I with the line of code can capture the Autopilot session id.

```
var sessionId = AutopilotAnywhere.sessionId;
```

I tried to set the line of code in the console, but I get undefined:

[image]

I am not quite sure how to use this line of code. Can anybody see how I use the line of code?

Comment: typing `var sth = sth` in console will always return `undefined`. Type just `AutopilotAnywhere.sessionId` or in the second line just `sessionId` to see what is in the variable

Comment: Than you a lot for your answer. I tried what you suggested in the console, and get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: AutopilotAnywhere is not defined(…)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
function getJSessionId(){
        var jsId = document.cookie.match(/JSESSIONID=[^;]+/);
        if(jsId != null) {
            if (jsId instanceof Array)
                jsId = jsId[0].substring(11);
            else
                jsId = jsId.substring(11);
        }
        return jsId;
    }
```

Comment: The `HttpOnly` flag is typically enabled on the `JSESSIONID` cookie in order to mitigate cross-site scripting attacks. `HttpOnly` prevents accessing a cookie from JavaScript like this.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I can see fson made a comment. But it is this direction I should go, or is it something else? To be quite honsest, I am in a little bit deep water on this water, regarding how I get that session id, so an user can be identified later on.